# mysqld is consuming cpu constantly

Tags: mysql, linux, ps

**my config:**

- CPU Intel Xeon (4 kernels) 2.13
- RAM 8G
- CentOS 6.4  kernel 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64
- mysql 5.1.67 , databases occupy about 1G

**and this is what i have:**

1. mysqld is consuming a lot of CPU, as soon as it is started
   ps -p `pidof mysqld` -o %cpu,%mem
   %CPU %MEM
   13.8  0.8
2. though there is no requests to it
   (monitored with mtop)
3. once requests to mysqld started, the %CPU value is rising(and never falls back), even up to 85%

what can be the reason?

Comment: what's the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` ?

Comment: try to use updated kernel.

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST shows nothing...